# Query with pagination not idempotent?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have this query for which I call the following hibernate method: query.list()

Before that I created the query as follows:

```
Query query = createQuery(filterQuery);
query.setFirstResult(first);
query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
setQueryParameters(query, filters, params);
```

Suppose my pageSize is 20, we're on the first page and I have 100 total records.

When I put a breakpoint before the query.list() and evaluate it twice in a row the first time I get 20 ( the correct amount ) and the second time I get 0.

Keep in mind that I am on a breakpoint so all parameters exactly the same.

How is it possible that the result of the query is not idempotent?

Comment: What do you mean by "twice in a row"?

Comment: I evaluate query.list() and I get 20. Then I evaluate it again and I get 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? Are you trying to use the same query object twice?

Comment: When I get on a breakpoint in the code. I can evaluate expressions in intelliJ. Just to be sure I tried to evaluate query.list(). When I did it two times I saw this behaviour

Comment: Then don't do that. Query objects are not multi-use. If you want to execute the same query twice, create a new one with your `createQuery` method.

Comment: It seems that Hibernate must be clearing some query config paramters after executing the query. The JPA spec says nothing explicit about reusing Query objects. On the other hand, it explicitly says that CriteriaQuery objects my be reused, so if doesn't say for Query object, we must assume that Query objects cannot be reused.